# Extra space in concatenated strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
includeString = '#include "' + className + '.h"'
```

where className evaluates to `myClass` gives

```
       #include " myClass.h"
```

note the extra space ^ after the quotes.

Obviously I am doing something very basic wrongly - but what? It is merely a coincidence that I am having this problem with a file name. This is a problem with strings, not file names.

I may well be forced to use `strip()`, but I would prefer to understand what is going wrong.

There is no leading space in `className`; here are those strings again, copied from PyCharm's evaluation, with enclosing singles quotes, as provided by PyCharm.

```
'includeString = '#include "' + className + '.h"'

'myClass'
```

Comment: Are you sure `className` doesn't have spaces?

Comment: Try includeString = '#include "{}.h"'.format(className.strip())

Comment: What @MarkR. said, or `includeString = '#include "' + className.strip() + '.h"'`

Comment: Then how would he include a file whose name did start with a space?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz if the OP has a file whose name starts with a space, that's a very bad naming convention. But in that case, the OP would need to show the code that generates the file name so that question could be answered.

Comment: Also a valid filename on NTFS.

Comment: Who said that a leading space isn't a problem? Not I, the OP

Comment: Why the downvotes? Presumably because there is **no way** that the string concatenation is adding an extra space, assuming `className` **is** a string (not some custom class with a weird `__add__`/`__radd__`) and **doesn't** have a leading space. Without providing an example that allows others to recreate the behaviour, there's really nothing we can do to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see an *extra* space that means there is one in your `className` variable. You need to remove it using `str.strip()` method like this: `a="   LOL   ".strip()`. This will result just in `"LOL"` with all spaces removed.

That will be `includeString = '#include "' + className.strip() + '.h"'` in your code.